# how to give data-autoplay attribute inside css in html website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, autoplay

i have a wordpress website, there is a slider in the homepage which is coming from some widget, the slider is static, when i inspected the element it was showing something like below:

```html
<div class="swiper-container services-slider swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal" data-cols="3" data-autoplay="0">
```

now i want the slider to autoplay automatically, as i am not able to edit the code of the slider i am trying to put some css in the head section of the website so the slider plays, how can i add autoplay attribute inside css, please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery something like this may work if the slider options have not already been rendered from the data attributes

```
$('.swiper-container').data('autoplay', 1)
```

Or

```
$('.swiper-container').attr('data-autoplay', 1)
```

With on ready

```
(function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.swiper-container').attr('data-autoplay', 1)
  });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i added this in heade section inside script tag, no changes

Comment: It probably needs to be in the footer not header. Also did you add it in jquery on ready as with all jquery code and do you have jquery loaded on the page? If you inspect the html can you see of the value was updated to 1?

Comment: Try the updated code (also try in head and footer). You were getting a jquery $ undefined error so wrapped it in a function to avoid conflicts. However I dont think this will work as I see when changing the attribute after render which is what jquery is doing does not set it to autoplay... but worth a try.

Comment: its working, but its moving so fast, how can i set time interval here

Comment: I am not sure as I don't know the slide options.. I guess a setting of speed would work `$('.swiper-container').attr('data-speed', 1200)` but without the sliders docs this is a guess

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider marking this as the correct answer. Thanks